# Remove unused uv space

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have several models with the same problem. Parts of the texture are not used and unnecessarily use up space.

Is there a methode to remove these spaces inside of Blender or is it better to adjust the textures in Photoshop?

(Baking gave unwanted results because of duplication if the objects are made real, or because of not being able to apply the scale when keeping them instanced.)

[image]

Comment: Hello, yes you need to do it in an image editor like Photoshop

Comment: Okay good to know, thank you moonboots!